# Scala: Cumulative String Tokenisation

Tags: strings, functional-programming, scala

I'm trying to split an incoming stream of strings into cumulative tokens per line item using a function below,

```
def cumulativeTokenise(string: String): Array[String] = {
  val array = string.split(" +")
  var result: Array[String] = Array()
  array.map { i => (
                    result = result :+ (
                                       if (result.lastOption == None) i 
                                       else result.lastOption.getOrElse("")+ " " + i
                                       ) 
                   )
             }
  result
}
```

Ex: output of cumulativeTokenise("TEST VALUE DESCRIPTION . AS") would be => Array(TEST, TEST VALUE, TEST VALUE DESCRIPTION, TEST VALUE DESCRIPTION ., TEST VALUE DESCRIPTION . AS)

Trying to figure out if there's another efficient in-built method in Scala or better ways of doing it with FP, without any mutable array. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried scanLeft where the initial parameter is an empty list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same results a little more directly.

```
def cumulativeTokenise(string: String): Array[String] =
  string.split("\\s+")
        .inits
        .map(_.mkString(" "))
        .toArray
        .reverse
        .tail
```

Or a, perhaps simpler, two step procedure.

```
def cumulativeTokenise(string: String): Array[String] = {
  val tokens = string.split("\\s+")
  Array.tabulate(tokens.length)(n => tokens.take(n+1).mkString(" "))
}
```

One problem I see here is that you rely on whitespace to separate tokens. That might not always be the case.

```
def cumulativeTokenise(string: String): Array[String] =
  string.split("((?=\\W)|(?<=\\W))")
        .filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)
        .inits
        .map(_.mkString(" "))
        .toArray
        .reverse
        .tail

cumulativeTokenise("here@there")
//res0: Array[String] = Array(here, here @, here @ there)
```

Probably not the best solution to the problem, but it's something to think about.

Comment: I like the Array tabulate approach, I'm using whitespace because that was the requirement given to me. Thanks jwvh